# Regex match character set without previous duplication

Tags: javascript, regex, text, dynamic, match

What is the best way to create a dynamic regex to match a distinct set of characters (characters and their order provided during runtime).

```
character set: abcd
character format: ??j? (question mark represents a a character from character set)
```

Example

```
abjd = match
bdja = match
dbja = match
ab = no match
aajd = no match
abjdd = no match
abj = no match
```

I have created a regex builder (in js) as follows:

```
// characters are the character set
// wordFormat is the character format
// replace(str, search, replacement) replaces search in str with replacement
var chars = "[" + characters + "]{1}";
var afterSpecialConversion = replace(wordFormat, "?", chars);

var myRegex = new RegExp("^" + afterSpecialConversion + "$", "gi");
```

Unfortunately this does not achieve the result as it does not consider duplicate items. I thought about using matching groups to avoid duplicates however I don't know how to negate the already existing character group from the remainder of the set.

Also given character set `aabcd` now `a` can exist twice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex-builder approach is correct (though a bit of a maintanability mess, so document it carefully), but not quite sophisticated enough. What you need to do is use [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

I've provided an [example regex on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gbzuOf/1) for the demo in your question.

The more general principle is to replace each set of `n` question marks with a pattern that matches this:

```
(?:([<chars>])(?!.*\<m>)){<n>}
```

Where `<chars>` is the character set you want to use, `m` is the index of the set of question marks (starting from 1 - more on this in a moment), and `<n>` is the number of question marks in the group. This yields regex-builder code that looks like this:

```
function getRe(pattern, chars) {
    var re = "^";
    var qMarkGroup = 1;
    var qMarkCount = 0;

    for (var index in pattern) {
        var char = pattern[index];
        if (char === "?") {
            qMarkCount += 1;
        } else {
            if (qMarkCount > 0) {
                re += "(?:([" + chars + "])(?!.*\\" + qMarkGroup + ")){" + qMarkCount + "}" + char;
                qMarkCount = 0;
                qMarkGroup += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Need to do this again in case we have a group of question marks at the end of the pattern
    if (qMarkCount > 0) {
        re += "(?:([" + chars + "])(?!.*\\" + qMarkGroup + ")){" + qMarkCount + "}";
    }
    re += "$";
    return new Regexp(re, "gi");
}
```

[Code demo on Repl.it](https://repl.it/ECSg/2)

Obviously, this function definition is very verbose, to demonstrate the principles involved. Feel free to golf it (but remember to watch out for fencepost issues like I've described in the comments).

Additionally, be sure to sanitize the inputs. This is an example and will break if someone, for instance, puts in `]` in `chars`.